# React app hosted on AWS S3 API requests fail

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, axios, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing a (single page) react app with `create-react-app` and it makes calls to my API which is AWS api gateway and AWS lambda. I'm trying to host the react app with AWS s3 static hosting.

When developing locally, requests (with `axios`) to my API are blocked because of missing CORS headers. To work around this I added a proxy to my AWS api gateway domain in my `package.json` file:

```
"proxy": "https://***.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

So requests work on my localhost where the app is hosted on a node development server. But I can't get this to work when the app is hosted on AWS S3. The `axios` requests to my API always fail with `403 Access denied` errors.

My question is, why are the requests failing, and what can I do to fix this?

**Edit:** I was able to get one of my API methods working by 1) enabling CORS in API gateway for the method in question and having my API return the headers:

```
{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
}
```

with the method response.

Now one of my POST methods isn't working at all even with the above changes, I'm getting a 405 "method not allowed" response. I really have no idea if I'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Please post your cors configuration. Because you may be missing something

Comment: Can you post the exact error

Comment: Also what kind of authorisation you are using for your API end point

Comment: @ArunK See edit. No authorization, and my cors configuration allows all origins (*) and all methods. I believe the issue is with aws API gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS on your API as your request are originating from an S3 domain https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: Yes sorry I should have mentioned I have added a cors configuration to s3 to allow all origins with a wildcard (*).

Comment: Handling preflight OPTIONS method in my lambda function seemed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the user app in [AWS IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/es/iam/).
If you don't configure the user after deployment, your app request will fail because of a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving method not allowed, you are trying to access via incorrect http method instead of the configured method. For example you have configured "POST" but trying to access via "GET"

Comment: My API gateway is configured to allow 'any' method and forward it to a lambda function to distinguish the method. Both GET and POST are supported. Again this all works when requests are proxied through a node server.

Comment: Is the request reaching the lambda according to logs

Comment: no this one is not. But the app is also doing a GET to the same method which works.

Comment: Try explicitly specify all methods instead of *

Comment: In lambda? It doesn't seem to be getting that far, API gateway isn't even calling my lambda.

Comment: Are you using serverless or SAM template. Let's not worry about cors. Did you try executing the api through postman?

Comment: I finally got everything working. I read through the API gateway enabling cors documentation and updated my lambda to handle OPTIONS method and return a 200 response with the CORS headers. All my API calls work now. Sorry this question became such a mess thank you for your help.